# Django audio file form validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, audio

I'm trying to add file validation to my Django project. Before I try and add a python library that will parse the file, I want to make sure I can check the file size, extension and content type. For my model form in forms.py I have:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

def clean_audio_file(self, form):
    file = self.cleaned_data.get('sound')


    if file:
        if file._size > 4*1024*1024:
            raise ValidationError("Audio file too large ( > 4mb )")
        if not file.content-type in ["audio/mpeg","audio/wav"]:
            raise ValidationError("Content-Type is not mpeg")
        if not os.path.splitext(file.name)[1] in [".mp3",".wav"]:
            raise ValidationError("Doesn't have proper extension")

            return file
        else:
            raise ValidationError("Couldn't read uploaded file")

class Meta:
    model = Places
    fields = [

        'title',
        'longitude',
        'latitude',
        'sound',

    ]
```

for my view, I have:

```
def post_create(request):
form= PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
form_class = PostForm()

if form.is_valid():     
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')


context= {
    'form': form,
}
return render(request, 'location/post_form.html',context)
```

I've gone through the Docs a few times, and looked for examples of similar file validation, but for some reason the files I upload are not getting validated. The form works as expected, but it still allows files that are too large and incorrect file types without raising the validation error. Any hints on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `clean_audio_file()` getting called? The form automatically calls [`clean_{field name}()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) and `clean()` when validating, but your field name is called `sound` instead. Renaming it to `clean_sound()` or just `clean()` since you don't already have one will work.

Also [`UploadedFile.size` is a thing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.size), not sure why you're looking at `_size` instead.